# How to Sort LiveData in ViewModel

Tags: sorting, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

In my **`Activity`**, I have a function which observes data in Firestore database and updates a LiveData ArrayList in the **`ViewModel`**:

```js
        businessViewModel.listenToAllSites().observe(this, Observer { allSites ->
            businessViewModel.updateAllSitesVMLiveData(allSites)
        })
```

The **`ViewModel`** returns LiveData from **`Repository`** as below:

```js
    fun listenToAllSites(): LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>> {
        return businessRepository.listenToAllSites()
    }
```

Which returns data from Firestore database Snaphot Listener in the form of LiveData as below:

```js
    fun listenToAllSites(): LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>> {

        if (allSitesRegistration == null) {
            allSitesRegistration = firestore.collection(SITES)
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "listenToAllSites(), listen error: ", e)
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                    }

                    val source = if (snapshot != null && snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites())
                        "Local"
                    else
                        "Server"

                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "listenToAllSites(): $source data: ${snapshot.size()}")
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "listenToAllSites(): $source data: null")
                    }

                    val allSites = ArrayList<SiteObject>()/**/

                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        for (document in snapshot) {
                            val site = document.toObject(SiteObject::class.java)
                            site.siteID = document.id
                            allSites.add(site)
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "updated 'allSitesMutableLiveData' (${allSites.size} x SiteObject)")
                    allSitesMutableLiveData.value = allSites
                }
        } else Log.d(TAG, "'allSites Listener' already exists (${allSitesRegistration.toString()})")

        return allSitesMutableLiveData
    }
```

In the **`ViewModel`**, the list gets updated as below:

```js
    fun updateAllSitesVMLiveData (allSitesList: ArrayList<SiteObject>) {
        _allSites.value = allSitesList
    }
```

I then have this and other similar lists to observe in my **`Fragments`** to populate RecyclerViews and which update on database changes - so for example:

```js
        // Observe All Sites & Filter for Current User
        businessViewModel.allSites.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { allSites ->
            if (allSites != null) {

                if(businessViewModel.filterSitesForUser.value == true) {
                    sitesAdapter.setList(allSites.filter { site -> site.users.contains(businessViewModel.currentUser.value?.userID)} as ArrayList<SiteObject>)
                } else sitesAdapter.setList(allSites as ArrayList<SiteObject>)

                sitesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                binding.sitesSearchFilterEditTextView.setText(searchViewInputText) // to reset filtered list after process death!

            }
        })
```

I also have a button which allows user to update list to see just **their** data or **all** data by toggling a `LiveData<Boolean>` in **`ViewModel`**, the change of which is observed in the **`Fragment`** as below:

```js
        // Observe sites filter status
        businessViewModel.filterSitesForUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { filterStatus ->
            if (filterStatus && !businessViewModel.allSites.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                binding.sitesUserIconImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.sitesUsersIconImageView.visibility = View.GONE
                sitesAdapter.setList(businessViewModel.allSites.value?.filter { site -> site.users.contains(businessViewModel.currentUser.value?.userID)} as ArrayList<SiteObject>)

            } else if (!filterStatus && !businessViewModel.allSites.value.isNullOrEmpty()){
                binding.sitesUserIconImageView.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.sitesUsersIconImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                sitesAdapter.setList(businessViewModel.allSites.value as ArrayList<SiteObject>)
            }
            sitesAdapter.filter.filter(searchViewInputText)
            sitesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

But what I am struggling with is best way to **sort** this data without disrupting the flow of data..  The user has the ability to sort list in different ways (sort by field, sort direction) and I have so far done this by updating the list in the repository (so the original observer is triggered) but I'm sure this sort of logic should not be in the repo (and I am creating a second list of data which is not ideal) but I can't see how to do it in the ViewModel:

```js
fun updateSitesOrderBy(field: String) {
        
        val sortedSites = ArrayList<SiteObject>()
        allSites.let { sortedSites.addAll(it) }

        if (field != orderBySites.value) {
            when (field) {
                DATE_CREATED -> orderBySites.value = DATE_CREATED
                DATE_EDITED -> orderBySites.value = DATE_EDITED
                SITE_TASKS -> orderBySites.value = SITE_TASKS
                SITE_RATING -> orderBySites.value = SITE_RATING
                else -> orderBySites.value = SITE_REFERENCE
            }
        }
                )


        sortedSites.sortBy { it ->
            when (orderBySites.value) {
                DATE_CREATED -> it.dateCreatedTimestamp.toString()
                DATE_EDITED -> it.dateEditedTimestamp.toString()
                SITE_TASKS -> it.siteTask.toString()
                SITE_RATING -> it.siteRating.toString()
                else -> it.siteReference
            }
        }
        
        )

        allSitesMutableLiveData.value = sortedSites
    }
```

Comment: have you looked into MediatorLiveData?

Comment: Thank you mfkw1, I'm looking into it now to see if it will work for me - I have found this example which I am digesting at the moment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDstIdTeRyo

Comment: You are missing `Transformations.switchMap()` in many places in your code.

Comment: Thank you both, hopefully I am on the right lines now - I have added follow up question as detailed below.

Answer (score 0):

I have now amended code to use `MediatorLiveData` as recommended by `mfkw1` as described in the below follow up question, which works except for the issue explained:

[Observing MediatorLiveData Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862724/observing-mediatorlivedata-issue)