# Observing MediatorLiveData Issue

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

I have the following `LiveData` variables in my `ViewModel` (simplified example):

```js
val currentUser : LiveData<UserObject>
val allSites : LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>>
val filterSitesForUser : LiveData<Boolean>
val orderSitesByField : LiveData<String>
val orderSitesDirection : LiveData<Query.Direction>
val searchFilterSitesText : LiveData<String>
```

I'm trying to use `MediatorLiveData` to have one 'stream' of data connecting to my `RecyclerView`.

I therefore also have the following code in the `ViewModel`, which is observed in the `Fragment`:

```js
   fun sitesList() : LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>> {

        val result = MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>>()
        
        result.addSource(currentUser) {
            result.value = combineSitesData(currentUser, allSites, filterSitesForUser, orderSitesByField, orderSitesDirection, searchFilterSitesText)
        }

        result.addSource(allSites) {
            result.value = combineSitesData(currentUser, allSites, filterSitesForUser, orderSitesByField, orderSitesDirection, searchFilterSitesText)
        }

        result.addSource(filterSitesForUser) {
            result.value = combineSitesData(currentUser, allSites, filterSitesForUser, orderSitesByField, orderSitesDirection, searchFilterSitesText)
        }
        
        result.addSource(orderSitesByField) {
            result.value = combineSitesData(currentUser, allSites, filterSitesForUser, orderSitesByField, orderSitesDirection, searchFilterSitesText)
        }

        result.addSource(orderSitesDirection) {
            result.value = combineSitesData(currentUser, allSites, filterSitesForUser, orderSitesByField, orderSitesDirection, searchFilterSitesText)
        }

        result.addSource(searchFilterSitesText) {
            result.value = combineSitesData(currentUser, allSites, filterSitesForUser, orderSitesByField, orderSitesDirection, searchFilterSitesText)
        }
        
        return result
    }
```

..along with this, also in the `ViewModel`:

```js
    private fun combineSitesData (
        currentUser: LiveData<UserObject>,
        allSites: LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>>,
        filterSitesForUser: LiveData<Boolean>,
        orderSitesByField: LiveData<String>,
        orderSitesDirection: LiveData<Query.Direction>,
        searchFilterSitesText: LiveData<String>
    ) : ArrayList<SiteObject> {

        var sitesList = ArrayList<SiteObject>()
        val userId = currentUser.value?.userID

        if (userId == null || allSites.value == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "combineSitesData() - currentUser or allSites value null")
            return sitesList
        }

        when (filterSitesForUser.value) {
            true -> sitesList.addAll(allSites.value!!.filter { site -> site.users.contains(userId) })
            false -> sitesList.addAll(allSites.value!!)
        }

        if (orderSitesDirection.value == Query.Direction.ASCENDING){
            when (orderSitesByField.value) {
                DATE_CREATED -> sitesList.sortBy { it.dateCreatedTimestamp }
                DATE_EDITED -> sitesList.sortBy { it.dateEditedTimestamp }
                SITE_TASKS -> sitesList.sortBy { it.siteTask }
                SITE_RATING -> sitesList.sortBy { it.siteRating }
                else -> sitesList.sortBy {it.siteReference}
            }
        }

        if (orderSitesDirection.value == Query.Direction.DESCENDING){
            when (orderSitesByField.value) {
                DATE_CREATED -> sitesList.sortByDescending { it.dateCreatedTimestamp }
                DATE_EDITED -> sitesList.sortByDescending { it.dateEditedTimestamp }
                SITE_TASKS -> sitesList.sortByDescending { it.siteTask }
                SITE_RATING -> sitesList.sortByDescending { it.siteRating }
                else -> sitesList.sortByDescending {it.siteReference}
            }
        }

        if (!searchFilterSitesText.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            var filteredList = ArrayList<SiteObject>()
            var filterPattern = searchFilterSitesText.value.toString().toLowerCase().trim()
            for (site in sitesList) {
                if(site.siteReference.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern) || site.siteAddress.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(site)
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "combineSitesData() - returned filteredList (size = ${filteredList.size})")
            return filteredList
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "combineSitesData() - returned sitesList (size = ${sitesList.size})")
        return sitesList
    }
```

This is the code in the `Fragment` which observes the list of Sites:

```js
        // Observe ViewModel SitesList
        businessViewModel.sitesList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { sitesList ->
            if (sitesList != null) {
                businessViewModel.currentUser.value?.userID?.let { sitesAdapter.setList(it, sitesList) }
                sitesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                Log.d (TAG, "setupViewModelObservers(): businessViewModel.sitesList().size = ${sitesList.size}" )
            }
        })
```

It seems to be working apart from the fact that when it is first observes, it fires off six times, which therefore updates my RecylcerView six times - when this is a large list, I see this being a bit of an issue!

After it initialises, it only updates once when any of the LiveData's change, so that's ok.

I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening, without holding a list in the Fragment or ViewModel to compare observed list to, which I am trying to avoid (as trying to follow MVVM architecture)..

EDIT: for clarity, I have added my `RecyclerViewAdapter` to show what the function `setList` does:

```js
class SitesRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private var currentUserId: String,
    private val onItemClickedListener: (SiteObject) -> Unit,
    private val onItemLongClickedListener: (SiteObject) -> Boolean
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var sitesList = ArrayList<SiteObject>()

    class SiteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val listItemBinding = SitesListItemBinding.bind(itemView)

        fun bind(
            userId: String,
            site: SiteObject,
            clickListener: (SiteObject) -> Unit,
            longClickListener: (SiteObject) -> Boolean
        ) {

            // Set text fields
            listItemBinding.sitesItemTitleText.text = site.siteReference
//            listItemBinding.sitesItemProjectsText.text = site.recentProjectsText TODO: Create way of showing recent projects with arrays

            //Reset Icons visibility
            listItemBinding.sitesItemTaskImageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            listItemBinding.sitesItemRating1ImageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            listItemBinding.sitesItemRating2ImageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            listItemBinding.sitesItemRating3ImageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            listItemBinding.sitesItemFavouriteImageView.visibility = View.GONE

            //Set sitePriority Icon visibility
            if (site.siteTask) listItemBinding.sitesItemTaskImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            //Set siteRating Icon visibility
            when(site.siteRating){
                1 -> listItemBinding.sitesItemRating1ImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                2 -> listItemBinding.sitesItemRating2ImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                3 -> listItemBinding.sitesItemRating3ImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            //Set siteFavourite Icon visibility
            if (site.users.contains(userId)) listItemBinding.sitesItemFavouriteImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            // Set Listeners
            listItemBinding.sitesItemCardview.setOnClickListener { clickListener(site) }
            listItemBinding.sitesItemCardview.setOnLongClickListener { longClickListener(site) }
            // Not set map listener?
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // LayoutInflater: takes ID from layout defined in XML.
        // Instantiates the layout XML into corresponding View objects.
        // Use context from main app -> also supplies theme layout values!
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        // Inflate XML. Last parameter: don't immediately attach new view to the parent view group
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sites_list_item, parent, false)
        return SiteViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = sitesList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Populate ViewHolder with data that corresponds to the position in the list
        // which we are told to load
        (holder as SiteViewHolder).bind(
            currentUserId,
            sitesList[position],
            onItemClickedListener,
            onItemLongClickedListener
        )
    }

    fun setList(userID: String, observedSites: ArrayList<SiteObject>) {
        currentUserId = userID
        sitesList = observedSites
        notifyDataSetChanged()  
        Log.d(TAG, "setList(), observedSites size = ${observedSites.size}")
    }

}
```

Comment: You can actually use https://github.com/Zhuinden/livedata-combinetuple-kt to reduce the code you need to write for the MediatorLiveData using `combineTuple(...).map { (a1, a2, ... a6) -> }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postValue` instead of `setValue`

> If you called this method multiple times before a main thread executed a posted task, only
> the last value would be dispatched.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am unsure where you are referring to in the code.  I have updated the question to show the function setList in the adapter in case this is what you are looking at..?